# Ruby on Rails 2 query on association count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This question is fairly similar to [1], except that I'm using Rails 2.3.5 (yes, old) and a complete newb at RoR. I have two models, Configfile and Signoff.

I want to find all Configfiles where the number of signoffs is < 2. Of course, I could do this by filtering the array manually, but this database is big and it's fairly slow.

```
class Configfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :computer
  has_many :signoffs,
           :dependent => :destroy
end
```

and

```
class Signoff < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :configfile
end
```

This seems like something that should be fairly easy to do in Rails, but I can't figure it out.
My query looks like this so far, and I haven't gotten anything that works for limiting it by the number of signoffs.

```
configs = c.configfiles.find(:all,
                             :include => :signoffs,
                             :order => 'filename')
```

[1] [Rails 3 query on condition of an association's count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313621/rails-3-query-on-condition-of-an-associations-count)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Configfile.find(:all, :group=>"configfile_id", :joins=>:signoffs, :having=>"count(*) < 2")
```

Which should give you the same as the equivalent rails3:

`Configfile.joins(:signoffs").group("configfiles.id").having("count_all < 2").count(:all)`

Comment: Thank you so much! The final solution I got working was:
`configfiles.find(:all, :group=>"configfile_id", :joins=>:signoffs, :having=>"COUNT(*) < 2")`
(changing count_all to COUNT(*) and .count to .find)