# How to search models when the condition rely on a relation attributes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, relational-database, where-clause

I have 2 models

```
class User
has_many :cars
end

class Car
belongs_to :user
end
```

I can do `User.where(...)` and test any user attribute

How do I test the attribute of relation?
For example, I want to do `'get all users where user.car.color = green'`? or `'get all users which have more than two cars'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`joins`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins):

```
User.joins(:cars).where('cars.color' => 'green')
```

And for the second one:

```
User.joins(:cars).group('users.id HAVING count(cars.id) > 2')
```

And putting those together:

```
User.joins(:cars)
    .group('users.id HAVING count(cars.id) > 2')
    .where('cars.color' => 'green')
```

See also: [Rails 3 query on condition of an association's count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313621/rails-3-query-on-condition-of-an-associations-count#answer-9370734)

Comment: how would I count the number of cars? `where('COUNT(cars) >2')` doesn't work

Comment: if you add, .where('cars.color' => 'green'), then that is the best answer

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work:

```
User.include(:cars).where("cars.color" => "green")
```

Comment: based on your additional question below, you could do something like this: `User.joins(:cars).select("users.id, users.first_name, users.etc, count(cars.id)").where("cars.color" => "green").group("users.id, users.first_name, users.etc").having("count(cars.id) > 2")`