# Use Rails .where to return objects with an association count greater than 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have the following method that returns all orders in current month that have a newspaper placement that is running.  An order has_many newspaper_placements.

```
def self.orders_with_placements_in_current_month(all_cc_mc)
  filter_start = Date.today.beginning_of_month
  filter_end = Date.today.end_of_month
  all_orders = []
  Order.where(client_companies_media_company_id: all_cc_mc).each do |x|
    if x.newspaper_placements.count > 0
      if (filter_start..filter_end).overlaps?(x.newspaper_placements.first.date..x.newspaper_placements.last.date)
        all_orders << x
      end
    end
  end
end
```

After the .where that is called on Order, I am including a conditional to see if the newspaper_placement count is greater than 0, because the code that follows it will fail if there are no placements returned.  Is there a way that I can only return orders that have a newspaper_placement count greater than 0 in my original query?  So what I want to do is have:

```
Order.where(client_companies_media_company_id: all_cc_mc)
```

return only orders with a placement count > 0, so I can eliminate the conditional that follows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3 query on condition of an association's count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313621/rails-3-query-on-condition-of-an-associations-count)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somethling like:

```
Order.joins(:newspaper_placements).where(client_companies_media_company_id: all_cc_mc)
```

Comment: Nice.  You may even be able to avoid the `having` clause (I think?) because the `joins` will filter out orders with no newspaper_placements... maybe?