# Find all objects that have greater than x of a certain association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have many `Farms` and each farm has many `animals`.  I need to find every farm that has more than 5 animals.

I need something along the lines of this...:

```
Farm.where(animals.count > 5)
```

**Update/Answer:**

```
Farm.joins(:animals).group("farm_id").having("count(farm_id) > 5")
```

Comment: I would use Parkash's answer if I were you. However you can also try out `squeel` gem. It might help

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
Farm.joins(:animals).group("farm.id").having("count(animals.id) > ?",5)
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9370734/429758

Comment: I believe this is close but it doesn't recognise `animals.id`

Answer (score 6):

Consider implementing [counter_cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html%23counter-cache) on Farm -> Animal

```
class Farm < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :animals
end

class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :farm, counter_cache: true
end
```

Don't forget to add `animals_count` (integer) to the `farms` table.

```
class AddAnimalCounterCacheToFarm < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :farms, :animals_count, :integer
    # if you need to populate for existing data
    Farm.reset_column_information
    Farm.find_each |farm|
      farm.update_attribute :animals_count, farm.animals.length
    end
  end

  def down
    remove_column :farms, :animals_count
  end
end
```

To find Farms with 5 or more Animals

```
Farm.where("farms.animals_count >= 5")
```

Comment: These lines didn't work for me:

    `Farm.reset_column_information
    Farm.find_each |farm|
      farm.update_attribute :animals_count, farm.animals.length
    end`

I replaced them with this to fix it:

`Farm.find_each { |u| Farm.reset_counters(u.id, :animals) }`