# How do I find all the Users with more than 1 Post in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to return all of the Users with more than 1 post in rails console.

A User `has_many :posts` and a Post `belongs_to :user`

I have messed around with the where method but I couldn't find anything. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `User.joins(:posts).where(posts: Post.all)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all objects that have greater than x of a certain association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665494/find-all-objects-that-have-greater-than-x-of-a-certain-association)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
User.joins(:posts).group('users.id').having('count(posts.id) > 1')
```

The `joins` method performs an inner join which results in all the users with a relationship to posts, and the `group` method is used to eliminate all duplicate rows.

Group by posts with `user_id`
i.e
example -

```
{
  1 => [post_1, post_2, post_3]
  2 => [post_5, post_10]
  ... so on
}
```

then apply `having` (prefered over `where` to work on aggregated data) clause `having("count(posts.id) > 1")`

[Having vs Where](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/having-vs-where-clause/)

[Find all records which have a count of an association greater than zero - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183710/find-all-records-which-have-a-count-of-an-association-greater-than-zero)

Comment: Hi! While this may be a solution to the question, code only answers are generally discouraged on SO. Please take some time to edit your response with an explanation as to why this is a solution as it will help OP and future visitors of the site.